# Eclipse not opening after JDK installation - Win 7 Machine 64 bit

Tags: windows, eclipse, windows-7

Eclpse IDE is not opening after JDK installation. After reading through couple of related posts. I added for path in environment variables below text

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javac;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

When I type path in cmd file this values get reflected.

Now I'm bit worried if I have to uninstall and check. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this for Windows, Mac, Linux?  By 'Not opening' what is the error, or what does it do when you try to start it?

Comment: If you are updating your PATH variable, it should simply have "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\", not point at specific executables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than fiddling with the `$PATH`, I would first set explicitly the jdk to use when launching eclipse, by editing `eclipse.ini` and adding those lines:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

See [this `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) as an example.

See also "[Eclipse crashes on start-up. Wrong eclipse.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955585/eclipse-crashes-on-start-up-wrong-eclipse-ini)" for more.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try by removing these two lines.

Edit the eclipse.ini file and remove these two lines:
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080509-1800.jar

Answer (score 0):

Siva,

For your eclipse to recognize your virtual machine you basically have 3 alternatives:

---

#### Method 1

Control Panel > Java > Java tab > click the View button.

Find your JVM installation and inside Runtime Parameters, put:

- -Djava.home=YOUR_JVM_PATH_HERE
- In your case: -Djava.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\

---

#### Method 2

You can set your JAVA_HOME https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521412/5626568

---

#### Method 3

How to specify your JVM direct inside config file:
[Eclipse workspace crashes on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597862/eclipse-workspace-crashes-on-startup/42227615#42227615)

---

#### Important to remember:

- For the 32-bit Eclipse executable (eclipse.exe on Windows) a 32-bit JVM must be used
- For the 64-bit Eclipse executable a 64-bit JVM must be used
- 32-bit Eclipse will not work with a 64-bit JVM

---

I hope this helps...

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

Eclipse IDE is not opening after upgrading your JDK.

#### Solution:

step 1 :Go to C:\Users"username"\eclipse"jdk version"\eclipse\eclipse.ini

step 2: update the path of -vm to the latest java bin folder

step 3: save and close the ini file , open your eclipse ... and you are ready to rock and roll again.