# Eclipse workspace crashes on startup

Tags: eclipse, crash, startup, workbench

I am using Spring Tool Suite(STS) 3.0.0 release (eclipse.buildId=3.0.0.201208091018-RELEASE-e42). It was running fine for a couple of months but lately my main workspace is crashing on splash screen with error as shown in last part of this post.

I have tried 'STS.exe -clean' and reverting installation(via new workbench) to a earlier configuration .. but nothing seems to work.

I was driving it as a single tool (i.e. almost all dev. related tasks even like connecting to server, database) so this is very frustrating :-(.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
            !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2012-11-28 08:56:53.195
            !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
            !STACK 1
            org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:186)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
                at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:68)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
                ... 11 more
            !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2012-11-28 08:56:53.195
            !MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
            !STACK 0
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:68)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
                at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
            !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2012-11-28 08:56:53.196
            !MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
            !STACK 0
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:68)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
                at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-11-28 08:56:53.210
            !MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 4 0 2012-11-28 08:56:53.213
            !MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
            !STACK 1
            org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:186)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
                at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:68)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
                ... 11 more
            !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2012-11-28 08:56:53.213
            !MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
            !STACK 0
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:68)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
                at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 2 2012-11-28 08:56:53.250
            !MESSAGE Problems encountered starting up plug-in: "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.wst.web_1.1.600.v201204190200 [797]".
            !STACK 0
            org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.wst.web_1.1.600.v201204190200 [797]
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:315)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:923)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getPlugin(Platform.java:738)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.InitLegacyPreferences.init(InitLegacyPreferences.java:43)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:147)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:166)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:237)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:410)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:663)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:805)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService$5.run(PreferencesService.java:623)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getNodes(PreferencesService.java:607)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getString(PreferencesService.java:676)
                at org.eclipse.wst.project.facet.ProductManager.getProperty(ProductManager.java:67)
                at org.eclipse.wst.project.facet.ProductManager.shouldUseViewerSyncForWebservices(ProductManager.java:127)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.webservice.startup.WebserviceListener.earlyStartup(WebserviceListener.java:79)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
            Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.wst.web_1.1.600.v201204190200 [797]
                ... 26 more
            Root exception:
            org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.wst.web_1.1.600.v201204190200 [797]
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:315)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:923)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getPlugin(Platform.java:738)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.InitLegacyPreferences.init(InitLegacyPreferences.java:43)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:147)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:166)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:237)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:410)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:663)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:805)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService$5.run(PreferencesService.java:623)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getNodes(PreferencesService.java:607)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getString(PreferencesService.java:676)
                at org.eclipse.wst.project.facet.ProductManager.getProperty(ProductManager.java:67)
                at org.eclipse.wst.project.facet.ProductManager.shouldUseViewerSyncForWebservices(ProductManager.java:127)
                at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.webservice.startup.WebserviceListener.earlyStartup(WebserviceListener.java:79)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 2 2012-11-28 08:56:53.258
            !MESSAGE Problems encountered starting up plug-in: "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]".
            !STACK 0
            org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:315)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:923)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getPluginForCompatibility(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:149)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:113)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
            Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]
                ... 15 more
            Root exception:
            org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:315)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:923)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getPluginForCompatibility(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:149)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:113)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-11-28 08:56:53.261
            !MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils 4 0 2012-11-28 08:56:53.263
            !MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
            !STACK 0
            java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getPluginForCompatibility(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:149)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:113)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
            Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered starting up plug-in: "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]".
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.throwException(PluginDescriptor.java:296)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:362)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
                ... 10 more
            Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:315)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:923)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
                ... 11 more
            Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]
                ... 15 more
            Root exception:
            org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered starting up plug-in: "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]".
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.throwException(PluginDescriptor.java:296)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:362)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getPluginForCompatibility(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:149)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:113)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
            Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:315)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:923)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
                ... 11 more
            Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException: The bundle's start level is not met.  Cannot transient start the bundle: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils_1.0.200.v201201032002 [553]
                ... 15 more

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-11-28 08:56:53.266
            !MESSAGE Bad extension specification

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.utils 4 0 2012-11-28 08:56:53.268
            !MESSAGE startup class must implement org.eclipse.ui.IStartup

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2012-11-28 08:56:53.422
            !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
            !STACK 0
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.legacyconversion.LegacyProjectChecker.earlyStartup(LegacyProjectChecker.java:36)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

            !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-11-28 08:56:53.424
            !MESSAGE Unhandled Exception
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: After trying a lot of things (a lot of hulaaluh!!) I finally figured out JRebel plugin which seemed to be creating this problem. My JRebel license had expired and this plugin used to give notification informing license expiry and asking to renew license. I used to ignore it, but when I acted on that notification (clicked ok) this problem didn't come up again!

Answer (score 42):

I faced the same problem. I followed these steps and it's working fine,

1. Go to your workspace e.g. C:\Workspace
2. Then open .metadata.plugins folder from your workspace.
3. Delete below 2 folders,

   - org.eclipse.e4.workbench
   - org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk

Eclipse should start after this.

Comment: For me it was sufficient to just remove `org.eclipse.e4.workbench `.

Comment: there are no folders with names: org.eclipse.e4.workbench
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk

Comment: Please be mindful that, while this works perfectly, it will also reset your workspace organization, so you will have to place all those perspectives in the way they were before. Minor inconvenience, but still worth noting.

Answer (score 13):

Solves the problem by eliminating the `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench` directory.

Answer (score 3):

For me the only solution was a simple adjustment in the **`eclipse.ini`**.

The file located in the **root** folder of the Eclipse installation.

---

Before the `-vmargs` line add the following:

> -vm
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

Example:

> -vm
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\javaw.exe
>
> -vmargs

---

#### Specifying the JVM

One of the most recommended options to use is to specify a specific JVM for Eclipse to run on. Doing this ensures that you are absolutely certain which JVM Eclipse will run in and insulates you from system changes that can alter the "default" JVM for your system. Many a user has been tripped up because they thought they knew what JVM would be used by default, but they thought wrong. `eclipse.ini` lets you be CERTAIN.

The following examples of `eclipse.ini` demonstrate correct usage of the -vm option.

Note the format of the `-vm` option - it is important to be exact:

- The `-vm` option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
- The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java
  executable, not just to the Java home directory.
- The `-vm` option must occur after the other Eclipse-specific options
  (such as `-product,` `--launcher`.*, etc), but before the `-vmargs` option,
  since everything after `-vmargs` is passed directly to the JVM.
- For the 32-bit Eclipse executable (`eclipse.exe` on Windows) a 32-bit
  JVM must be used and for the 64-bit Eclipse executable a 64-bit JVM
  must be used.

---

> #### Important: 32-bit Eclipse will not work with a 64-bit JVM

---

#### Reference:

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after opening a Kepler workspace with Luna and then switch back to Kepler. Seems that Luna added some data unexpected by Kepler.

I had to remove the .metadata folder and configure the workspace again.

Comment: I didn't have to rollback to the previous version. Deleting `.metadata` worked for me. Problems started when I requested installing live preview for angula in eclipse (oxygen 2).

Answer (score 1):

What I did when I had this problem was deleting the .lock inside the crashing workspace's .metadata folder.

Worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Error Got removed by deleting org.eclipse.e4.workbench in workspace.metadata.plugins folder... :)