# Java eclipse strange crash

Tags: java, eclipse, crash

Yesterday my Eclipse (luna) was working pretty fine. Today, when I launched it for the first time, I went into my project and start coding. 
Then I saved with ctrl + S. When I did this, Eclipse stop responding. 
I quited, relaunched, and re-did a ctrl + s, and Eclipse re-crashed, without any error messages.

I uninstalled Luna, installed Kepler instead, same problem. I have deleted my workspace, re-built a new one ... Still crashing.

Things I noticed is that there is always "Building project" in background after I saved, and the percentage is at 0 everytime.

Any clue to solve my problem ? Thank you.

Comment: see the config ini file

Comment: might want to check if java is compiling properly. try compiling something from the command line.

Comment: Also  check the eclipse folder for log files.

Comment: Also check you hard disk

Comment: Ok so I guess I found the clue. 
First of all, i guess i had a problem with my file system. When I deleted a repository and then tried to copy / paste the same repository at the same path, windows said "files are alreay existing ..." and when I pressed "replace all", it crashed.

I have reboot my computer, and workspaces i deleted before the reboot were still here. I guess it was part of the problem. 
Then I built a totally new workspace, moved required files and removed  the <buildCommand> tag in the .project file. 

It works fine now, thank for clues !

Answer (score 1):

I would try these steps to resolve:

1. Execute your Eclipse.exe as Administrator
2. If not work, delete the path .metadata inside your workspace and open again
3. Specify your JVM. Example: [Eclipse workspace crashes on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597862/eclipse-workspace-crashes-on-startup/42227615#42227615)
4. Try with JVM 1.7 and 1.8 too (some plugins only work with Java 8)
5. Re-install your JVM and try again

Perform one step at a time and try to open Eclipse with each modification.

I hope this helps...

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with your project compiling. Try to reinstall the JDK, might work.