# JBoss Developer Studio Crashes shortly after starting

Tags: windows, jboss-developer-studio

Today I started JBoss Developer Studio (devstudio.exe) again and it crashes almost immediately after starting. Exit code is -1073740781.

I've also reinstalled Devstudio 10.2.0.GA and it doesn't work either.

Workspace does not matter, it also crashes in a new one.

Running it from eclipsec.exe, instead of devstudio.exe, works.

Unfortunately, there's no log file created. Anybody knows what to do to debug this further?

[image: DevStudio crash]

Comment: Diego, follow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42299628/5626568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

devstudio.exe is just a copy of eclipse.exe. The fact eclipse.exe works and devstudio.exe does not makes me think the problem could be in devstudio.ini file.

My wild guess is -Dosgi.framework.extensions system property could be in charge for jvm crash. Everything else in the message looks sane to me.

Comment: Yes! I removed `-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension` from devstudio.ini and now it's not crashing. Now I need to do some research about that extension :)

Comment: Here is the link https://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT/Equinox_hook_for_Nashorn

Answer (score 0):

Install in standard location (under C:\Program Files) and test again

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a problem with the spaces in your JDK path. Try using the /x (short directory) path, eg.,

- launch `CMD.exe` from Windows start menu (or other launcher)
- `cd c:\`
- `dir /x`
- note that`Program Files folder` is also named `PROGRA~1`
- use this path as your JDK path when starting Eclipse/devstudio: `c:/progra~1/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/javaw.exe`

You could also try `visualvm` or `jstat` -- see [Tool for debugging hangs in java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833497/tool-for-debugging-hangs-in-java-application) for more details.

The exit code itself could be a -1 followed by the processID of the process running Eclipse/devstudio.

See also:

- [Difference in System. exit(0) , System.exit(-1), System.exit(1 ) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java)
- [Java exit codes and meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454114/java-exit-codes-and-meanings)