# Eclipse crashing on start-up

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, crash

I am using Eclipse Neon.1 and the program seems to be crashing on start-up. I am currently running Eclipse on Linux Mint 18. Before giving the information for the crash I want to point out that for some reason Eclipse doesn't always crash. For instance, it might work once then not again for several attempted startups.

First of all, the crash always happens whenever the loading screen says "`loading org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.core`". Below is the error message that is given when I run eclipse through the terminal. I am using the official Oracle Java version jdk1.8.0_112.

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd8f1bf7fe8, pid=6348, tid=0x00007fd8f32f8700
 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0x4f0fe8]  ConstantPool::klass_name_at(int)+0x28
 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/xxxxxx/Software/Eclipse/eclipse/hs_err_pid6348.log
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp*
```

I can add the full bug report file as well if someone finds it necessary.
It would be a huge help if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: "Failed to write core dump" sounds like your issue. Did you try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982396/failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled)?

Comment: Try to set your JVM into eclipse.ini file. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597862/eclipse-workspace-crashes-on-startup/42227615#42227615

Answer (score 0):

/home/xxxxxx/Software/Eclipse/eclipse/hs_err_pid6348.log

contains your info about the crash. Have you checked it?